CORS Error on Page Refresh in .NET Application Running on IIS
I have a .NET application (VueJS) running on IIS that has been experiencing CORS-related issues for the past two months. Initially, everything worked perfectly, but now, whenever a user refreshes a page, the frontend cannot connect to the backend, and a CORS error appears in the console log.
This issue only happens when the page is refreshed. When a user initially clicks to open a page, the connection works as expected without any errors.
Error message:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:55000/employees/getEmployees' from origin 'http://localhost:55000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross-origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, data, http, https, isolated-app.

In my backend code, I configured CORS like this:
private void configureCors(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var clientAddresses = Configuration.GetSection("ClientAddress")
       .Get<string[]>();

    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(name: VUE_CORS,
            builder =>
            {
                builder.WithOrigins(clientAddresses)
                       .AllowAnyHeader()
                       .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
    });
}

ClientAddress: "http://localhost:55000"
The data is being requested using Axios in Vue.js:
getEmployees (searchData) {
      this.$http()
        .get('/employees', { params: searchData })
        .then(({ data }) => {
          this.tblEmployeeData = data
        })
    },


What is the actual value of var clientAddresses?

Also, please share your JS code where you're making the request.

Hi hud., may I know if we can face the cors issue when using kestrel ?
